# Blocking socket returns EAGAIN

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

One of my projects on Linux uses blocking sockets. Things happen very serially so non-blocking would just make things more complicated. Anyway, I am finding that often a `recv()` call is returning `-1` with `errno` set to `EAGAIN`.

The `man` page only really mentions this happening for non-blocking sockets, which makes sense. With non-blocking, the socket may or may not be available so you might need to try again.

**What would cause it to happen for a blocking socket? Can I do anything to avoid it?**

At the moment, my code to deal with it looks something like this (I have it throw an exception on error, but beyond that it is a very simple wrapper around `recv()`):

```
int ret;
do {
    ret = ::recv(socket, buf, len, flags | MSG_NOSIGNAL);
} while(ret == -1 && errno == EAGAIN);


if(ret == -1) {
    throw socket_error(strerror(errno));
}
return ret;
```

**Is this even correct?** The `EAGAIN` condition gets hit pretty often.

**EDIT:** some things which I've noticed which may be relevant.

1. I do set a read timeout on the socket using `setsockopts()`, but it is set to 30 seconds. the `EAGAIN`'s happen way more often than once every 30 secs. **CORRECTION** my debugging was flawed, `EAGAIN`'s don't happen as often as I thought they did. Perhaps it is the timeout triggering.
2. For connecting, I want to be able to have connect timeout, so I temporarily set the socket to non-blocking. That code looks like this:

   ```
   int      error = 0;
   fd_set   rset;
   fd_set   wset;
   int      n;
   const SOCKET sock = m_Socket;

   // set the socket as nonblocking IO
   const int flags = fcntl (sock, F_GETFL, 0);
   fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

   errno = 0;

   // we connect, but it will return soon
   n = ::connect(sock, addr, size_addr);

   if(n < 0) { 
       if (errno != EINPROGRESS) {
           return -1;
       }
   } else if (n == 0) {
       goto done;
   }

   FD_ZERO(&rset);
   FD_ZERO(&wset);
   FD_SET(sock, &rset);
   FD_SET(sock, &wset);

   struct timeval tval;
   tval.tv_sec = timeout;
   tval.tv_usec = 0;

   // We "select()" until connect() returns its result or timeout
   n = select(sock + 1, &rset, &wset, 0, timeout ? &tval : 0);
   if(n == 0) {    
       errno = ETIMEDOUT;
       return -1;
   }

   if (FD_ISSET(sock, &rset) || FD_ISSET(sock, &wset)) {
       socklen_t len = sizeof(error);
       if (getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len) < 0) {
           return -1;
       }
   } else {
       return -1;
   }

   done:
   // We change the socket options back to blocking IO
   if (fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, flags) == -1) {
       return -1;
   }
   return 0;
   ```

The idea is that I set it to non-blocking, attempt a connect and select on the socket so I can enforce a timeout. Both the set and restore `fcntl()` calls return successfully, so the socket should end up in blocking mode again when this function completes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's possible that you have a nonzero receive timeout set on the socket (via `setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,...)`) as that would also cause recv to return `EAGAIN`

Comment: yes, but it is set to 30000 milliseconds, I get the EAGAIN's *way* more often than that. Pretty much constatnly.

Comment: *CORRECTION* my debugging was flawed, EAGAIN's don't happen as often as I thought they did. Perhaps it is the timeout triggering.

Comment: For anyone who want a reference, [check here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) and search "SO_RCVTIMEO".

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you're using `MSG_DONTWAIT` is being specified as part of your flags?  The `man` page says `EAGAIN` will occur if no data is available and this flag is specified.

If you really want to force a block until the `recv()` is somewhat successful, you may wish to use the `MSG_WAITALL` flag.

Comment: I just grepped my source tree, MSG_DONTWAIT is not used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest this as a first-attempt fix, but if you're all out of options, you can always `select()` on the socket with a reasonably long timeout to force it to wait for data.

Answer (score 0):

`EAGAIN` is generated by the OS almost like an "Oops! I'm sorry for disturbing you.". In case of this error, you may try reading again, This is not a serious or fatal error.  I have seen these interrupts occur in Linux and LynxOS anywhere from one a day to 100 times a day.