# Sockets: Why does a blocking read() fail with ENOTCONN?

Tags: c, sockets, io, blocking, nonblocking

I am trying to read from a blocking socket, but I am wondering that `read()` returns -1, which I think means that there's currently no data to read - I would expect that it blocks until it can read the amount of bytes.

I also tried ensuring that the socket is in blocking mode and that a high timeout is set using:

```
int setBlockingIO(int fd)
{
       int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
       fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags & (~O_NONBLOCK));
       int nTimeout = 30000; // 30 seconds
       setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&nTimeout, sizeof(int));
}
```

But this hasn't changed anything.

**My question:**

- What do I have to do that `read()` will `really block?`
- Are there some pitfalls which I might hit? (bug in my program?)

I know that there's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735249/blocking-socket-returns-eagain) on this topic, but there I cannot find the answer for my question.

**UPDATE**

Without setting a timeout, `read()` also returns (subjectivly) immediately -1

**UPDATE 2**

`errno` is 107 (`ENOTCONN, Transport endpoint is not connected)`.
But the client side has not closed the connection in the meanwhile (ensured by a long `sleep()` after `write()` )

Comment: `man read` and read `errno` to determine the error that occurred, and not necessarily in that order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that either there was a time-out, or possibly a signal interrupted the read. You can use the results of `errno` in `errno.h` to see what the error is, and if you want the error in a human-readable formating, you can use either `strerror()` or `perror()` from `string.h` or `stdlib.h`

**Update:** According to the POSIX specification, you should be passing a `struct timeval` (defined in `sys/time.h`) set to the desired number of seconds and microseconds before a timeout occurs to `setsockopt` when specifying the `SO_RCVTIMEO` flag rather than casting an `int` to a `const char*`.  So even though your client may be mis-behaving and causing a different error right now, you could still end up with problems further down the line if you're sending the wrong argument types to the function.

Comment: Thank you. The reason is that the connection has already been closed by the client (because of unexpected client behavior, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018974/sockets-what-is-causing-read-to-return-einval )

Comment: After fixing the client side, the same error is back. I've updated the question.

Comment: Okay, I've added an update to my answer that hopefully helps out.

Comment: If the above updated answer didn't help, what happens if you use a default-configuration on the socket without `O_NOBLOCK` set or any timeouts?  Does `read()` still return immediately?

Comment: Yes, the behavior is the same.

Comment: Can you post the code on how the connection itself is setup?  If you are getting the same error on a socket that has no timeouts and is set to block on `read()`, then I would be curious to see how the actual setup of the file-descriptor is taking place ... I don't think the problem is necessarily in the current code that's been posted.

Answer (score 4):

What do you expect? You said you have a non-blocking socket so of course it does not block. The behavior for a non-blocking socket on `read` is to immediately return with some data (possibly shorter than the requested amount) if data is available to read, and to return -1 with `errno` set to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` if no data is available.

If you don't want non-blocking behavior, why did you set the socket to be non-blocking?

**Edit:** Grr, you've changed your question. The reason for `ENOTCONN` is that you're trying to read from a socket that is not connected. Unless a socket was obtained by `accept` or `socketpair`, you must call `connect` on it to connect it to a remote address before `read` will work.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is in errno. Likely scenarios:

- `[ECONNRESET]` The d argument refers to a socket, and the remote
  socket end is forcibly closed.
- `[EAGAIN]`     The file was marked for non-blocking I/O, and no data
  were ready to be read.

Basically, you make non-blocking blocking using:

```
do
{
    read(...);
} while(errno == EAGAIN);
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns -1 when it times out.

Don't set a timeout and it will block forever (Well, at least while the socket is still connected, anyway).

Comment: The timeout is set to 30 seconds, but it seems to return immediately (<0.1 seconds). But even without setting a timeout the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.
Thank you for all your comments, they had been a great help.

The problem was the usage of the **wrong file descriptor**.

I passed the file descriptor of the **server socket** to `read()`, instead of the file descriptor of the **client socket** which `accept()` returned.

Comment: Glad you figured out the problem :-)

Comment: Then you could accept one of the answers that told you to check `errno`, or whatever helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`read()` could block, so if there's no data available it will return `-1` and set `errno` to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.

If you wand to use `read()`, you could use `select()` or `poll()` to wait for availability of data on the socket.

Comment: This is wrong. In blocking mode, read() will not return EAGAIN ( except an (optionally) timeout is reached). You are describing non-blocking reads.