# Sockets: What is causing read() to return EINVAL?

Tags: c, sockets, io, blocking, nonblocking

A socket client program establishes a connection with the server,
writes some bytes and waits for response using the (blocking) `read()`.

But this fails with the error `EINVAL` ("Invalid argument").
Previous calls to `create()`, `bind()` and `connect()` the socket have been made successfully.

**My Question**

- What's wrong here?

Platform is Linux x64.

Comment: ... and tell use what platform you're on.

Comment: Indeed, you need to post code. `EINVAL` usually indicates a careless mistake (maybe as simple as misordered arguments) and as such it's impossible to diagnose without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I passed a size of 1 byte to the `read()` function.
It seems that this is not supported 
*(why? what is the minimum size? must it be a multiple of 2/the bitness of the platform?).*

Now I am passing 8 and it works.
Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: There's no such thing as "bitness of the platform". You likely had/have a bug somewhere and it happens to work. You should provide the code to us.

Comment: You shouldn't accept it as answer, because that' not the reason why it don't work previously!

Answer (score 2):

> fd is attached to an object which is
>   unsuitable for reading; or the file
>   was opened with the O_DIRECT flag, and
>   either the address specified in buf,
>   the value specified in count, or the
>   current file offset is not suitably
>   aligned.

See http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html

Comment: Please avoid linking to `die.net` man pages. They're very outdated, but at the top of Google results because of a feedback effect of people finding them and linking them as answers to questions. The up-to-date and authoritative copies are at `kernel.org`.